# What is this assumption about a graph in Reinhard Diestel's Graph Theory 5th Edition? $V \cap E = \emptyset$.

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I am reading Reinhard Diestel's Graph Theory 5th Edition.
What is this assumption about a graph in Reinhard Diestel's Graph Theory 5th Edition?
The author says "To avoid notational ambiguities, we shall assume tacitly that $V \cap E = \emptyset$.".
But $E$ is a set of $2$-element subsets of $V$.
So, I think that $V \cap E = \emptyset$ is always satisfied and the author didn't need to assume that.
Please give me an example of a graph $G$ such that $V \cap E \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a purely set-theoretical viewpoint, there is no reason $V$ cannot intersect $E$. For instance if $V = \{a, b, \{a,b\}\}$, then $E = \{\{a,b\}\}$ is a set of 2 element subsets of $V$ with non-empty intersection to $V$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very nice example.

Comment: These are undirected graphs so we technically want $V = \{a, b, \{a,b\}\}$ and $E = \{\{a,b\}\}$ in this example.